# How to get info of embed google map in iframe?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests-html

In [this page](http://www.dsit.org.ir/?cmd=page&Cid=92&title=Kontakt&lang=fa), I need to get link of first google map but i get in trouble. :)

this is my code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = "http://www.dsit.org.ir/?cmd=page&Cid=92&title=Kontakt&lang=fa"
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
results = r.html.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "google-maps-link", " " ))]')
print(results)
```

as you try, results is an empty array, and i don't know how to fix it.

I need this link in view larger map:
https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=35.774875,51.444822&z=14&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=embed&cid=7274660908916026251

tnx for your helpping!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Beautifulsoup and requests for that!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("http://www.dsit.org.ir/?cmd=page&Cid=92&title=Kontakt&lang=fa").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

soup2 = str(soup.find('p',dir="rtl"))

link = soup2.split("src=\"")[1].split('\"')[0]

print(link)
```

The output of this is the link:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6474.17339460898!2d51.44385684982641!3d35.773246637195555!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x64f4c98dc95c2b8b!2z2q_ZiNiq2Yc!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1401633826037
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this link has no information, i need this link: https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=35.774875,51.444822&z=14&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=embed&cid=7274660908916026251

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve you problem With a different look.

**First** you cant access it content but you can access to its data, you need to find the `src` of your iframe at begin

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

page = requests.get("http://www.dsit.org.ir/?cmd=page&Cid=92&title=Kontakt&lang=fa")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
ifarme = soup.find('iframe')
ifarme_src = ifarme['src']
```

**Second** you Need to request this new site and get Your required information So I get the whole page like before :

```
locations_properties = requests.get(ifarme_src)
googleMapData = re.findall(
    r'initEmbed\((.+)\)', locations_properties.text)[0]
```

Now you have all the registered information about your location in Google Map like **telephone** or **Address** and **Lat & long** or **web site domain** and etc.

For more accessibility and readability, we clean the Data

```
dataList = re.findall(r'\".*?\"', googleMapData)
dataList = list(map(lambda this_elm: this_elm.replace('"', ''), dataList))
```

Now you have your clean Data List like this :

```
['spotlight', '0x0:0x64f4c98dc95c2b8b', 'گوته', 'a', 'en_US', '', '/maps/api/js/ApplicationService.GetEntityDetails', '/maps/embed/upgrade204', '/maps/embed/record204', 'hwfnX5_7GsGWkwXwtpuoCA', '0x3f8e043a6fae1571:0x64f4c98dc95c2b8b', 'Tehran, Daroos، Eslamiyeh, No. 10، Goethe German language School', '7274660908916026251', 'Goethe German language School', 'Tehran', 'Daroos', 'Eslamiyeh, No. 10', '79 reviews', 'http://www.google.com/search?q=Tehran,+Daroos%D8%8C+Eslamiyeh,+No.+10%D8%8C+Goethe+German+language+School\\u0026ludocid=7274660908916026251#lrd=0x3f8e043a6fae1571:0x64f4c98dc95c2b8b,1', '021 2260 6146', '/url?q=http://www.dsit.org.ir/%3Flang%3Dde\\u0026sa=U\\u0026ved=0ahUKEwjf2onVr-vtAhVBy6QKHXDbBoUQ61gIFCgQMAA\\u0026usg=AOvVaw3Eo6luqHt02uvaNdlLSVgx', 'dsit.org.ir', '0ahUKEwjf2onVr-vtAhVBy6QKHXDbBoUQ61gIFCgQMAA', 'Language school', 'Tehran, Daroos، Eslamiyeh, No. 10', 'http://www.google.com/search?q=Tehran,+Daroos%D8%8C+Eslamiyeh,+No.+10%D8%8C+Goethe+German+language+School\\u0026ludocid=7274660908916026251#lrd=0x3f8e043a6fae1571:0x64f4c98dc95c2b8b,1', '79 reviews', 'ChIJcRWubzoEjj8RiytcyY3J9GQ', '0ahUKEwjf2onVr-vtAhVBy6QKHXDbBoUQ8BcIAigAMAA', 'موسسه آموزش زبان آلمانی گوته', 'tel://+982122606146', '0ahUKEwjf2onVr-vtAhVBy6QKHXDbBoUQqtMBCA0oCjAA', '8H7HQCFV+XW', 'QCFV+XW Tehran, Tehran Province','Saturday', '9AM–9PM', 'Sunday', '9AM–9PM', 'Monday', '9AM–9PM', 'Tuesday', '9AM–9PM', 'Wednesday', '9AM–9PM', 'Thursday', '9AM–9PM', 'Friday', 'Closed', 'Saturday', '9AM–9PM', 'Open ⋅ Closes 9PM', 'Open until 21:00']
```

**Third** You can now find all the data you need with regex, for example I find all the domains in this data list:

```
for this_element in dataList:
    if re.search(r'www\.(?!google).+\..{2,8}/', this_element):
        print(re.findall(r'(www\.(?!google).+\..{2,8})/', this_element)[0])
```

And the output is :

```
www.dsit.org.ir
```